# D3.js - How to change position of labels on zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a zoom function which works perfectly fine for circles, but not for labels.

```
svgEnter.attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.translate + ')scale(' + d3.event.scale + ')');
```

How to "attach" labels to circle, so it follows parent when users scroll or zoom?

Here is an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/seveneleven/z4m5c06a/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if anyone wondering: plain text nodes is the way to go.

```
var ne = node.enter()
  .append('a')
  .attr('class', function(d) {
    return d.style + '-bubble-node';
  })
  .attr('alt', function(d) {
    return '#' + (encodeURIComponent(idValue(d)));
  })
  .call(force.drag)
  .call(connectEvents);

ne.append('text')
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name
  });

ne.append('circle')
  .attr('r', function(d) {
    return rScale(rValue(d));
  });
```